# How do I put a SQL Server database under version control using Visual Studio Community 2015 RC?

Tags: sql-server, git, visual-studio, sql-server-2008-r2, visual-studio-2015

I would like to put my database schema and its data in my git repository and have it version controlled, just like my code.

I have SQL Server 2008 R2 and Visual Studio Community 2015 RC. I know that Visual Studio 2010 upwards, Database project templates have been introduced to do just this. Please see [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833194%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for example. But I don't find those templates in my Visual Studio Community Edition 2015 RC installation.

Answer (score 0):

Sticking to RC isn't very viable in the long term. Especially now, when Visual Studio 2015 RTM has been released.

Unless you have some really strong incentive to stay on Release Candidate, I would recommend to:

1. Get [RTM Express Edition](https://www.visualstudio.com/products/mt238358) for free, whichever suits you best. SSDT 2015 is compatible with [Web and Windows Desktop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/mt186501);
2. Get [SSDT 2015](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx) (again, for free) and install on top of that.

AFAIR, that should give you SQL Server database projects and everything else you might need. The only catch is that, as usual, it will be a somewhat longer route if you have ever had any CTP / RC versions installed on the same Windows instance before. Then again, it's nothing new.

Comment: Given that the OP is on the Community RC, I would suggest an upgrade to Community RTM, not Express RTM. It's more prominantly featured on the page you link to too, yet you still suggest to install the Express version?

Comment: @hvd, that's probably because I'm not exactly sure what the Community edition actually is. So yes, chances are, the OP's options are even better.

Comment: Ah, okay. Community edition is basically Professional edition, made available free of charge, with a few license restrictions that the Express editions do not have. [Organisations may be affected by those license restrictions, but indivual developers shouldn't be, not even if they want to use the software commercially.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dorischen/archive/2014/11/12/q-amp-a-on-visual-studio-community-2013-and-2015-preview.aspx).

Comment: Well, the problem is, I don't see it mentioned among the ones SSDT is compatible with (second link in my post). If it counts as Professional there, that's good; but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: @hvd, thanks for bringing this matter and for the link. Apparently, it suits me, too, so I wouldn't have to cram myself in Express version(s) :)

Comment: A quick note - SSDT is built into Visual Studio including Community edition. In the "Typical" install some parts such as LocalDB are not installed so I would recommend customizing it to select "SQL Server Data Tools" as part of the initial VS installation. For the latest updates the page Roger linked to is a great start, or you can update via Extensions and Updates inside Visual Studio.